# Regexp to find Googlebot with http status code 200 in apache logs

Tags: regex, apache, grep, tail

I am looking for a regular expression to filter just the lines from Googlebot that have a status code of 200, like this one:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [02/Feb/2012:12:21:26 +0100] "GET /some/url/here HTTP/1.1" 200 9823 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
```

And not show this one that is a redirect (301 status code):

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [02/Feb/2012:12:23:36 +0100] "GET /other/url HTTP/1.1" 301 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
```

I am currently using: `tail -f access_log | grep Googlebot`

That shows me all crawling by Google, but I have seen here that you can also use regexp when doing tail on the log:
http://www.electrictoolbox.com/view-apache-logs-tail-grep-egrep/

Any other recommendation on a tool that provides a better way for filtering logs is welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

how about

```
grep 'HTTP[^"]*" 200 .*Googlebot/2.1' log
```

Answer (score 3):

Or the much simpler

```
tail -f access_log | grep "Googlebot" | grep 200
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there must be something better, but this works with the examples you provided

```
.+?\[.+?\] ".*?" 200 .+Googlebot.+
```

With egrep:

```
tail access.log  | egrep '.+?\[.+?\] ".*?" 200 .+Googlebot.+'
```

Comment: As I told Steve, my requirement is to show only lines that also match with Googlebot. So the regex must match with both Googlebot and 200 status code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, I would use `awk`:

`awk '$9 ~ /^200$/ { print $0 }' file.txt`

If you're only interested in the last 10 growing lines, you can try:

`tail -f access_log | awk '$9 ~ /^200$/ { print $0 }'`

EDIT:

I should have been more strict, try:

`awk '$9 ~ /^200$/ && $14 ~ /^Googlebot/ { print $0 }' file.txt`

or

`tail -f access_log | awk '$9 ~ /^200$/ && $14 ~ /^Googlebot/ { print $0 }'`

Comment: Thanks, it works, but my requirement is to show only Googlebot entries, with this code I see all 200 status codes.